# vb6 - how to get the remote computer name based on the given IP address

Tags: vb6

how can i get the remote computer name based on a given IP Address in vb6? Is there any way that i can list out a list of computers linked to current computer?

Comment: Is this within a tightly constrained LAN? Outside of such situations, there's no 1-1 correspondence between machines and IP addresses. Also, are you trying to discover this information in real time, or from e.g. logs?

Comment: Yes, it is connected through LAN and i want to get the computer name on run time when user enters the server IP address in my application. is this possible?

Comment: When you say "computer name", do you mean the computer's fully qualified domain name in the DNS system, or do you mean its "computer name" in windows (i.e. its NetBIOS name)?

Comment: computer name in windows so that i can use it to access the computer remotely. i currently using UNC add to access to the server e.g \\server1

Comment: You can use IP addresses in UNC paths. I don't think there's anything easy to resolve IP->Machine name in VB6 - you might have to run a command line command, capture the output (I think this is reasonably easy in VB6, if I remember right), and the parse that output.

Comment: I try to make my app more flexible by allowing user to enter either IP add or machine name. However, there's some of my process which needs to computer name. If were to use command line, can you provide me some example? as i' m really very very new in vb6

Comment: This is why people should control access to administrative shares, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_share

Answer (score 3):

If reverse DNS lookup does what you want this might help.  This example simplifies the processing of the DNS results, but should get you started and may be enough:

```
Option Explicit

Private Const DNS_TYPE_PTR = &HC
Private Const DNS_QUERY_STANDARD = &H0
Private Const DnsFreeRecordListDeep = 1&

Private Enum DNS_STATUS
    ERROR_BAD_IP_FORMAT = -3&
    ERROR_NO_PTR_RETURNED = -2&
    ERROR_NO_RR_RETURNED = -1&
    DNS_STATUS_SUCCESS = 0&
End Enum

Private Type VBDnsRecord
    pNext As Long
    pName As Long
    wType As Integer
    wDataLength As Integer
    Flags As Long
    dwTTL As Long
    dwReserved  As Long
    prt As Long
    others(9) As Long
End Type

Private Declare Function DnsQuery Lib "Dnsapi" Alias "DnsQuery_A" ( _
    ByVal Name As String, _
    ByVal wType As Integer, _
    ByVal Options As Long, _
    ByRef aipServers As Any, _
    ByRef ppQueryResultsSet As Long, _
    ByVal pReserved As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function DnsRecordListFree Lib "Dnsapi" ( _
    ByVal pDnsRecord As Long, _
    ByVal DnsFreeRecordListDeep As Long) As Long

Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" ( _
    ByRef pTo As Any, _
    ByRef uFrom As Any, _
    ByVal lSize As Long)

Private Declare Function StrCopyA Lib "kernel32" Alias "lstrcpyA" ( _
    ByVal retval As String, _
    ByVal PTR As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function StrLenA Lib "kernel32" Alias "lstrlenA" ( _
    ByVal PTR As Long) As Long

Public Function IP2HostName(ByVal IP As String, ByRef HostName As String) As Long
    Dim Octets() As String
    Dim OctX As Long
    Dim NumPart As Long
    Dim BadIP As Boolean
    Dim lngDNSRec As Long
    Dim Record As VBDnsRecord
    Dim Length As Long
    'Returns DNS_STATUS Enum values, otherwise a DNS system error code.

    IP = Trim$(IP)
    If Len(IP) = 0 Then IP2HostName = ERROR_BAD_IP_FORMAT: Exit Function
    Octets = Split(IP, ".")
    If UBound(Octets) <> 3 Then IP2HostName = ERROR_BAD_IP_FORMAT: Exit Function
    For OctX = 0 To 3
        If IsNumeric(Octets(OctX)) Then
            NumPart = CInt(Octets(OctX))
            If 0 <= NumPart And NumPart <= 255 Then
                Octets(OctX) = CStr(NumPart)
            Else
                BadIP = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Else
            BadIP = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If BadIP Then IP2HostName = ERROR_BAD_IP_FORMAT: Exit Function

    IP = Octets(3) & "." & Octets(2) & "." & Octets(1) & "." & Octets(0) & ".IN-ADDR.ARPA"

    IP2HostName = DnsQuery(IP, DNS_TYPE_PTR, DNS_QUERY_STANDARD, ByVal 0, lngDNSRec, 0)
    If IP2HostName = DNS_STATUS_SUCCESS Then
        If lngDNSRec <> 0 Then
            CopyMemory Record, ByVal lngDNSRec, LenB(Record)

            With Record
                If .wType = DNS_TYPE_PTR Then
                    Length = StrLenA(.prt)
                    HostName = String$(Length, 0)
                    StrCopyA HostName, .prt
                Else
                    IP2HostName = ERROR_NO_PTR_RETURNED
                End If
            End With
            DnsRecordListFree lngDNSRec, DnsFreeRecordListDeep
        Else
            IP2HostName = ERROR_NO_RR_RETURNED
        End If
    'Else
        'Return with DNS error code.
    End If
End Function
```

Note however it does not handle NetBIOS names.

Comment: Reverse DNS is indeed what he wants, as failure to resolve an address to a name with DNS results in a NetBIOS lookup. :-)

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Microsoft support article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/138086), the standard `GetHostByAddr()` functions should do it.  Unfortunately, I can't find any examples of how to do a `GetHostByAddr` call in VB6, but perhaps someone else can help with that part.  Alternately, you could run a commandline tool like nslookup:

```
bensonk@hunter ~/Desktop/cont $ nslookup 64.34.119.12
Server:     208.67.222.222
Address:    208.67.222.222#53

Non-authoritative answer:
12.119.34.64.in-addr.arpa   name = stackoverflow.com.
```

That example was run on a linux machine, but the same command will work fine on windows.

Answer (score 0):

MOST SIMPLE TECHNIQUE EVER

To send computer name ,
Do this:

Create a textbox,

Change its multiline property to true.

After that, in the text property of that textbox, write this:

```
echo %computername% >> C:\temp.txt
```

then, using `Fileinput`, input the textfile and input the textfile `C:\temp.txt`.

If you want to use this for sending over winsock or LAN, Send the text box text using `winsock1.sendata`

Done